# Black overlay on collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overlay

I am trying to get a black overlay on the rest of my page when a div is collapsed. Here is my code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#filter').on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
            if (e.type == 'show') {
                $('body').addClass('overlay');
            } else {
                $('body').removeClass('overlay');
            }
        })
    })
</script>

<div href="#filter" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#filter">
    Filter your results
</div>
<div class="search collapse show" id="filter" aria-expanded="true">
    <!-- Some code -->
</div>
<!-- Rest of page -->

<style>
    .overlay{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background: black;
        opacity: 0.5;
        display: block;
        z-index: 2;
}
</style>
```

The problem with this code is that the background of my body becomes dark with an opacity of 1 and the rest of the page is also dark with an opacity of 0.5.

I want only the **search div** to be apparent and the rest with a dark overlay with the 0.5 opacity.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure if this would work but you could try to make an extra class for the search div, in which you override the properties you don't want it to have, so like background and opacity. I might be stupid and you might be already doing that, if so, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying the overlay class to the body, which means you are applying all the `.overlay` css to your body, ie. your entire page. The `.overlay` should be a separate element, so add a div with the class name overlay and instead of addClass/removeClass you show/hide the `.overlay`. Also the `z-index` of the `.overlay` should be higher than the rest of the page and the `z-index` of the search bar should be even higher.

Comment: I added this: 
<div class="overlay" style="display: none;"></div> after my <body> tag. 

I also changed the z-index as per your suggestions. and I changed the JS to : 
let overlayDiv = document.querySelector(".overlay"); 
if (e.type == 'show') {
    overlayDiv.style.opacity = 1;
  } else {
    overlayDiv.style.opacity = 0;
}

It is not working.

Comment: "display:none" will not be overridden by opacity.Use  $('.overlay').show(); and  $('.overlay').hide(); instead.

Comment: thank you. The only issue is that if I click outside the search div the overlay still shows

Comment: You can add click event for the overlay to hide it. $( ".overlay" ).click(function() {
  this.).hide();
});